# how to redirect stdout and stderr of a called script to the same values of the caller?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a script `a.sh` which does this

```
args="--conf myconf=2"
/usr/bin/b.sh $args
```

when I do this, I don't see anymore the stdout of b.sh.
Also, I would like to be able to redirect b.sh stdout and stderr to the same values specified for a.sh, for example if a user calls `a.sh 1> out.txt 2> err.txt` I want to see the stdout of b.sh in out.txt and the stderr of b.sh in err.txt

Comment: file descriptors (incl. `stdout`/`stderr`) are inherited by child on `fork()` and unless set not to preserved across `exec()`. In other words, if your process/script has `stdout`/`stderr` redirect somewhere, any child process/script it calls does use the same redirection. Perhaps your `b.sh` does something else (hardcoded) with its outputs?

Comment: if I simply run this `/usr/bin/b.sh --conf myconf=2` I see prints on the terminal. if I run using a.sh, I don't

Comment: It really must be something that is in the `b.sh`, so you may need provide a bit more details to reproduce. Try creating simple `echo FOO` script `b.sh` and run it through `a.sh` as above.

Comment: That should be the default behaviour. Does your `a.sh` have any other content except these two lines?

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt of what's happening with the redirection, add this to you `b.sh` script

```
#! /bin/bash
lsof -d 0,1,2 -a -p $$
...
```

and you can check where the FD's 0,1 and 2 are redirected.